# Implementing PKI on an Active Directory domain

Tags: certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services, pki, active-directory-adcs

I would like to implement a two-tier PKI in a relatively small Windows environment:  about 35 users and five virtual servers.  Although I have little experience with Linux, I am trying to use [XCA](https://hohnstaedt.de/xca/) on a Linux-based virtual machine as the offline root certification authority because I'm not sure that I could justify paying for Windows Server licensing for a computer that will be off most of the time.

I have found two sets of instructions for the configuration I want to implement.

- https://4sysops.com/archives/use-openssl-based-software-xca-as-offline-root-certificate-authority-for-ad-certificate-services/
- [https://wiki.ledhed.net/index.php?title=ADCS_with_Linux/BSD_based_Offline_Root_CA](https://wiki.ledhed.net/index.php?title=ADCS_with_Linux/BSD_based_Offline_Root_CA%60)

However, I am afraid of doing this wrong and these instructions seem lacking to me.  I have been researching this for weeks, and I have several questions.

#### One Tier or Two?

Some people suggest that the size of the business does not warrant a two-tier PKI and that I should instead have a single, online certification authority.  I'm not entirely opposed to that configuration, buy my understanding is that recovering from a compromised online root CA is much more difficult than recovering from a compromised intermediate/subordinate/issuing CA when the root CA is offline.  Is that correct?  Would I have to have the online root CA on a server that handles no other programs or services because the server might have to be rebuilt if it is compromised?  Does a two-tier hierarchy allow me to use the server that runs the issuing CA for additional purposes?

#### AIA and CDP URLs

I attempted this once before with a Windows root CA. I have in my notes from that time to execute the following script on the root CA.

```
# VARIABLES
$HTTPUrl = "pki.mycompany.local"

# AIA
certutil -setreg CA\CACertPublicationURLs "1:C:\Windows\system32\CertSrv\CertEnroll\%1_%3%4.crt\n0:ldap:///CN=%7,CN=AIA,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,%6%11\n0:http://%1/CertEnroll/%1_%3%4.crt\n0:file://%1/CertEnroll/%1_%3%4.crt\n2:http://$HTTPUrl/pki/%3%4.crt"

# CDP
certutil -setreg CA\CRLPublicationURLs "65:C:\Windows\system32\CertSrv\CertEnroll\%3%8%9.crl\n0:ldap:///CN=%7%8,CN=%2,CN=CDP,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,%6%10\n0:http://%1/CertEnroll/%3%8%9.crl\n0:file://%1/CertEnroll/%3%8%9.crl\n6:http://$HTTPUrl/pki/%3%8.crl"

Restart-Service -Name CertSvc -Verbose
```

I can't find any equivalent procedure for XCA. In fact, I have read that the AIA and CDP URLs should not be set on the root CA. Would they be set in the properties of the issuing (Windows) CA?

#### IIS

Does IIS need to be on a server other than the issuing CA?

#### CAPolicy.inf

Some instructions I've read describe modifying the file CAPolicy.inf; others do not.  Some instructions mention an OID; others do not.  My understanding is that CAPolicy.inf is helpful but not necessary.  If I create it, can I just omit the OID?  Do I need to get a private OID using the procedure described at https://www.keyfactor.com/blog/establishing-a-private-oid/?

#### OCSP

I often read that OCSP is recommended, but I can't find many guides about implementing it. Can anyone recommend some resources?

#### Resources

These are the resources I plan to consult for the configuring the Windows portion. If you have better guides, please share.

- https://stealthpuppy.com/deploy-enterprise-subordinate-certificate-authority/
- https://www.derekseaman.com/2021/03/windows-server-2019-two-tier-pki-ca-pt-2.html

Answer (score 1):

### One Tier or Two?

The argument that your environment is small does make some sense.  The purpose of a root CA is really two-fold:  in a multi-CA environment it aggregates your trust-anchors into one, which simplifies management of the trust-anchor in relying parties' stores; and (if kept truly offline) it helps mitigate the trust-anchor distribution problem in the event that the issuing CA is compromised, by being designed to never be compromised in the first place (i.e. offline with strict physical and procedural controls).

It sounds like the 1st purpose isn't applicable to you. However, your environment may grow and if a second issuing CA appears in the future you may be glad that you already have a root CA to sign it?

The 2nd purpose might sound like it isn't applicable to you, but again, things may change over time.  Also a Microsoft Windows domain is somewhat helpful in this area as you can use AD or Group Policy to distribute and/or remove the trust-anchor, but if you have an single level PKI and the worse happens, are you confident that AD/Group Policy will be able to remove the CA certificate from *all* your relying parties?  Even the ones you forgot about, or the laptop that's offline at the moment because the user is on the road?

If your environment is virtual, there's very little benefit in having your root CA as another VM.  Nobody can say, hand on heart, that the VM is offline. It might be powered off, but it can be powered on, and it would have backups (it should do) which can be cloned and powered up.  If you insist on using a VM, then make sure that you use some form of encryption at rest on the disk image and keep the passphrase for that extremely secure.  Then worry that nobody will come along in a couple of years time and notice the VM hasn't been powered up for a while and therefore delete it without checking. That's where those backups come in handy...

An alternative in a virtual environment would be to buy a laptop and install the root CA on that.  When not in use, lock it in a safe.  You would still need some strong processes in place around it to make sure nobody else can access it, and nobody finds it in 10 years time (gathering dust) and decides it's for recycling!  You would also need to take backups of this laptop after each use, to an encrypted HDD maybe, which would also need to be protected to the same level.

The more you research this, the more you'll realise that PKI isn't really about the technology (its only a handful of servers) but more about the processes and procedures you put in place to make it a trustworthy service.

### AIA and CDP URLs

These would be set in the issuing CA certificate, as you correctly read. It will be applied to the issuing CA certificate by the root CA (XCA).

XCA permits you to generate a template which is used to apply such settings.  Simply generate a new CA template (based on the built-in CA template) and set the Type to Certification Authority and the Path length to 0 (and critical) to ensure no entity below this issuing CA certificate can become another CA.  Enable both Subject Key Identifier and Authority Key Identifier on this template, and set the CRL Distribution Point to be the URL to where you will host the CRL generated by XCA (e.g., `http://pki.mycompany.local/cdp/rootCA0.crl`).  You will need to some manual process to upload the XCA generated CRL to that location.

There is no need to have the AIA caIssuer set on the issuing CA certificate, as the issuer is the root CA, which all relying parties must have installed in their trust-anchor store.  That is, they will never need to use this extension to find the root CA certificate.

While you are editing this template, set the Key Usage to Critical and select Certificate Sign and CRL sign (only).  Do not select any Extended Key Usages.

Remove everything from the Netscape tab (it's the year 2023!)

The Microsoft system of using variables in the CRL Distribution Point and Authority Information Access settings isn't available in XCA. But neither is it needed.  In the Microsoft world, it is used to automatically generate the CRL, certificate names, and paths, and can be useful when you re-key the CA certificate for example.  For the XCA root CA, you only have one - the URL where the CRL is downloaded - so it would be overkill to use variables.  Such a feature might be useful in XCA if it was used as an issuing CA, but I don't believe its been implemented.

### IIS

IIS does need to be on a server other than the issuing CA. That's because it should *never* be installed on a CA in a production environment.

The CA is a high value service which needs protecting.  Consider adding firewall rules so that only your subscribers can access it.  The IIS service for your CRLs is a service which should be accessible from all relying parties regardless of where they are situated. Strict firewall rules would be a hindrance here.  If you hosted IIS on the CA you would need quite open firewall rules which increases attack surface.  If IIS was compromised, the attacker could access your CA keys.

Put your IIS service on a separate server to the CA.

Saying that, there is no PKI Police and I've seen many implementations where this advice is ignored in the interest of simplicity and cost saving.

### CAPolicy.inf

Probably not required.  If you don't want all the ADCS templates enabled you could add:

```
[Certsrv_Server]
LoadDefaultTemplates=0
```

It's very unlikely that you need to register an OID.  It will not bring you any benefit other than some kudos in a PKI convention.  The number of relying party software that checks OIDs is extremely limited, so it becomes merely a tag added to an issued certificate.  If you decide to write strict governance documentation to manage your PKI service, then you may need to consider using OIDs, but you would need to understand the governance principles first before you dive in to this minefield.

### OCSP

OCSP can be useful if you expect to revoke may certificates as it reduces the requirements for your relying parties to download large CRLs (large, because they get bigger as you revoke certificates).

OCSP can also help enable revocation in web-browsers, which these days tend to ignore CRLs.  The browser vendor support for CRLs and OCSP differ, so some research is required here if you insist that browsers check certificate for revocation.

[The Microsoft docs](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/987.windows-pki-documentation-reference-and-library.aspx#Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol_OCSP) are worth a read.

### Resources

Why trust some random blogs to such an important security service?  What's wrong with Microsoft resources for configuring their products?  Examples:

[Microsoft PKI Docs Reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/987.windows-pki-documentation-reference-and-library.aspx)

[Securing PKI: Monitoring Public Key Infrastructure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn786432(v=ws.11))

[ADCS Security Guideance](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10942.ad-cs-security-guidance.aspx)

[Understanding Certificate Revocation Checks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/04/07/understanding-certificate-revocation-checks/)

[How Certificates Work (2K3 era, but useful info on settings and internals)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc776447(v=ws.10))

[How Certificate Revocation Works (2K8 era)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee619754(v=ws.10))

If you really must venture outside of Microsoft, then I'd suggest [PKI Solutions](https://www.pkisolutions.com/) as a trustworthy source, or [Sysadmins LV](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/default.aspx).

Finally, now that I've mentioned *trustworthy* sources, you now have to ask yourself whether you trust my ramblings :-)

### Finally

Do build this in a lab first.  To create a trustworthy service you need to ensure that the production build goes smoothly, which means it shouldn't be the first time you've tried this.

Comment: Thank you very much for this in-depth and helpful reply.

Could you explain what you mean by "adding firewall rules so that only your subscribers can access it?"

I inherited an Active Directory domain that is not routable; the domain name ends with ".local."  We don't have any public-facing resources.  Does that information change whether IIS should be on a different server?  I can't see the benefit of putting IIS on another server on the domain, but, as I'm sure you can tell, I'm in over my head.

Comment: Are variables in the CDP URL (e.g., http://pki.mycompany.local/cdp/%3%8.crl or http://pki.mycompany.local/cdp/<CAName><CRLNameSuffix>.crl) strictly a Microsoft feature, or can they be used in XCA as well?  Should I use them on the issuing CA?


I do consult Microsoft's documentation, but, in my opinion, it is often aimed at much larger business environments, and it tends to overwhelm me.

Comment: You asked whether I would be confident in my ability to remove all certificates in a single-tier PKI in the worst case.  I would not, but honestly I would not know what to do in the worst case with a two-tier PKI either.  I can find many articles and videos about implementing PKI, but I haven't seen much about what to do when things go wrong.  For example, people will say that an online root CA on an Active Directory domain can be rebuilt in an hour or two, but they don't link to any instructions.  Can you point me to any information about what to do if the issuing CA is compromised?

Comment: I've tweaked my answer for your 1st two additional questions, but the third is too big IMHO for a tweak.  It's a topic/question in its own right.  As to the people who can rebuild a online root CA in an hour or two, you need to ask them a) why so slow - haven't they heard of PowerShell, and  b) can they _guarantee_ that the old root CA certificate has been removed from _all_ relying parties?  This latter point is the important one, not their speed.